# Trouble Connecting to AWS RDS Aurora in Different Availability Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I am facing a strange issue with AWS RDS Aurora configuration.

I am operating in the region us-east-2 (Ohio) and have set up a VPC. In each availability zone (us-east-2a, us-east-2b, us-east-2c), I have one public and one private subnet, all with default configurations.

Strangely, when I create an RDS instance in us-east-2b, I am able to connect from my local machine without any issues. However, I can't connect if I create an RDS instance in either us-east-2a or us-east-2c.

I have come across some answers suggesting that I should have only public subnets in the VPC to be able to connect, but that doesn't seem to be the entire story since I can connect from the availability zone us-east-2b without any issues.

My knowledge of AWS is limited, and I'm unable to debug this problem effectively. I would greatly appreciate any help or insights from the community to understand what might be causing this connectivity issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Edit: Attached the subnet route tables.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this statement "and have set up a VPC in each of the 3 availability zones"? You didn't create 3 VPCs did you? You created one VPC, with subnets in 3 AZs, correct?

Comment: This statement: "I have come across some answers suggesting that I should have only public subnets in the VPC to be able to connect, but that doesn't seem to be the entire story since I can connect from the availability zone us-east-2b without any issues." makes no sense. You can have public and private subnets in any availability zone. Just because the subnet is in `us-east-2b` doesn't indicate that it is public or private. I think you are focusing on the different availability zones when those are probably irrelevant, and you should be focusing on the subnet route tables.

Comment: Correct Mark. I have created one VPC, with subnets in 3 AZs. I have edited the statement for better clarity.

Comment: So looking at the updated question, the availability zone does indeed appear to be irrelevant. The important detail that is still missing from the question is what **specific** subnets the Aurora cluster is deployed to. You have two subnets per AZ (one public, one private). Which of those subnets is the database in?

Comment: Based on their private IPs, I have determined that the instance running in us-east-2b is in a public subnet, while the one in us-east-2c is in a private subnet, which isn't accessible. 
However, I couldn't recall setting any public/private subnet assignment options during the setup process. 
Additionally, both instances were marked as publicly accessible.

Comment: You have to select the list of subnets to deploy the RDS/Aurora cluster to when you create the cluster. You should be able to see those in the RDS web console in your DB cluster's configuration settings. For a DB to be publicly accessible, it has to be deployed to a public subnet, and it has to have "publicly accessible" enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. It worked after creating an RDS instance with a DB subnet group having only public subnets. However, I am still unable to understand how the subnet assignment happened earlier, where one RDS was created in a public subnet and another in a private subnet. Is it random, or is there some logic behind that?

Comment: No it is not random, you had to manually pick those subnets from the list of all available subnets. You just don't remember doing it.